# Ship to different address check box to radio button

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove ship to different address check box and change it to radio button with yes and No. I can't find any way to do so. Any suggestion?

```
<h3 id="ship-to-different-address">
    <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox">
        <input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'shipping' === get_option( 'woocommerce_ship_to_destination' ) ? 1 : 0 ), 1 ); ?> type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address" value="1" /> <span><?php _e( 'Ship to a different address?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
    </label>
</h3>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Yasir, Unfortunately your question doesn't have nearly enough information for anyone to provide an answer. Where is that code coming from? Is this a custom theme?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to edit the template file, `form-shipping.php`. In that file change the code that you have displayed with following.

```
<h3 class="radio-toggle">
    <span><?php _e( 'Ship to a different address?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
    <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-radio radio" style="margin-left:15%;">
        <input id="ship-to-different-address-radio-yes" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-radio input-radio" type="radio" name="ship_to_different_address_radio_toggle" value="1" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'shipping' === get_option( 'woocommerce_ship_to_destination' ) ? 1 : 0 ), 1 ); ?> /> <?php _e( 'Yes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </label>
    <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-radio radio" style="margin-left:5%;">
        <input id="ship-to-different-address-radio-no" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-radio input-radio" type="radio" name="ship_to_different_address_radio_toggle" value="0" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'billing' === get_option( 'woocommerce_ship_to_destination' ) ? 1 : 0 ), 1 ); ?> /> <?php _e( 'No', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </label>
    <span id="ship-to-different-address"><input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'shipping' === get_option( 'woocommerce_ship_to_destination' ) ? 1 : 0 ), 1 ); ?> type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address" value="1" style="opacity:0;" /></span>
</h3>
```

Also, add the following code snippet into `functions.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'toggle_shipping_address' ) ){
    function toggle_shipping_address(){
        global $post;
        if($post->post_name === 'checkout'){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.radio-toggle .input-radio').change(function(){
                var curval = ($(this).val() === '0') ? true : false;
                $('#ship-to-different-address-checkbox').prop('checked', curval);
                $('#ship-to-different-address-checkbox').trigger('click');
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'toggle_shipping_address' );
```

This will result in changing the checkbox to Radio buttons with labels 'Yes' and 'No'. Below is screenshot for your visual reference. This is along with the functionality of expanding and collapsing the preceding div of shipping address form.

Hope this helps.

[image: Screenshot of resulting structure]

Comment: Thanks you so much boss. you save my client and my life... stay blessed

Comment: Hello,Hope you are fine, i need one more help from you.. The radio button script you send me, is not working with new wordpress update. can you please help me out

Comment: WordPress update should not affect the customization you have done. Have you updated the theme that you have customized?

Comment: yes.. i did.. theme is not supporting it what to do now?

Comment: Can you let me know the theme name and whether it is a free theme or a paid theme?

Comment: this is enfold.. paid theme

Comment: Did you create a child theme of for making the customisation? If not you need to make the child-theme so that you do not loose the customisation of parent theme upgrade.